# Where can I find simple exercises to practice string manipulation in Perl?

Tags: perl, string, collections

Does anyone know where I can find a collection of very simple exercises on string manipulation in order to practice Perl language?

I'm learning Perl just to use the resources it has got of string manipulation.

Answer (score 6):

[Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113) book has lots of exercises as far as I recall.

Also, search StackOverflow on "perl" and ("regex" or "split") and try to answer any questions yourself and then go and understand other people's answers

Also, go through any string manipulation tasks on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Welcome_to_Rosetta_Code) and do them in Perl

Answer (score 2):

You could do this simply with [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore). Do your manipulations and then test your guess:

```
my $subs1 = substr( 'apple', 0, 1 );
is( $subs1, 'a' );
```

The underlying testing system will usually tell you what you guessed wrong. If you did this in [REPL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aREPL) (since it's very linear), it could serve as a training exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with

```
my $s = 'PERL';
$s =~ s/PERL/Perl/;
```

or

```
$s = ucfirst lc $s;
```

Comment: You work far too hard, Sinan: `perl -E 'say "PERL" =~ s/\B\p{Lu}/\l$&/gr'`

Comment: @tchrist - the idea is to have beginners exposed to the code that looks like it was NOT already ciphered.

Comment: @DVK — you seem to’ve mistaken my previous gem for `ˋwhich perl5.13.6ˋ -E 'say $^X =~ s#/?\K\w+(?\!.*/)#\u\L$&#r'`. Not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 0):

`perldoc -q string`